# Is it considered a bad practice to modify a reference variable without returning anything in C#?

Tags: c#, methods, reference

Is it considered a bad practice if you modify a reference variable in a method without returning it?

For example:

```
public Widget GetWidget()
{
    Widget widget = FetchWidget();
    ApplyPartNamePrefixes(widget);
    return widget;
}

public void ApplyPartNamePrefixes(Widget widget)
{
    widget.PartName1 = String.Format("{0}{1}", "*", widget.PartName1);
    widget.PartName2 = String.Format("{0}{1}", "**", widget.PartName2);
}
```

Comment: As shown, that method feels like it should be an instance method on the Widget class and instead of taking a parameter widget, operate on the current instance (this).

Comment: However, even as written, it's pretty clear by your method name that you are changing something, so I think you're safe here.

Answer (score 2):

No, that's fine. That's the point of reference variables. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is fine if the method you are calling documents that it will change values in the object. This could be either through XML documentation or through a good naming convention. You have `ApplyPartNamePrefixes(Widget widget)` which somewhat implies that it will change the state of the widget however if you had `DoStuff` which is vague or something like `GetData` then that would be a rather painful experience if it changed the objects state.